# Alternative to Numerous Jquery Append for Ajax/Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am creating a data heavy application with lots of use of Ajax and Javascript.

It is really beginning to struggle when selecting values which return a huge amount of data.

This is more of a discussion than a question, but would anyone know of a more efficient way of doing the below?  It is also in a loop which may be called up to 5000 times, as you can imagine this is very browser heavy.

```
           .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('wo')
              .append($('<h2></h2>')
                  .text(item.WorksOrderNumber + '/A-' + item.OperationNumber)
              )
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('handle')
              .append($('<span></span>')
                .addClass('icon-move')
              )
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('partno')
              .append($('<span></span>')
                  .addClass('secondary radius label')
                  .text(item.PartDescription)
              )
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('quantity show-for-medium-up')
              .append($('<span></span>')
                  .addClass('secondary radius label')
                  .text('x' + item.PlannedQuantity)
              )
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('date')
              .append($('<span></span>')
                  .addClass('secondary radius label')
                  .append($('<span></span>')
                    .addClass('icon-clock')
                    .text(' ')
                  )
                  .text(item.PlannedStartDate)
              )
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('status')
              .append($('<span></span>')
                  .addClass('secondary radius label')
                  .text(item.WorksOrderOperationStatus)
              )
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('colour colour-' + item.Colour)
            )
            .append($('<li></li>')
              .addClass('preceding')
              .append($('<span></span>')
                .addClass('secondary radius label')
                .text('Preceding: ' + item.Preceding)
              )
            )
```

[image: Example of the presentation etc]

Comment: If you're doing bulk appends then it's better to make one large html string and append that, even if it's huge.  It will be much quicker than creating lots of individual elements and appending them.

Comment: Why don't you use a table instead with some kind of pagination? TABLE should be used to display data

Comment: You'd generally do something more like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/65SZn/**, with more structure etc.

Comment: I had same problem and got low performance on rendering huge datasets by html. I was only able manage this by partial loading. My application only loads data via Ajax that should be visible on viewport at the moment. If a visitor scrolls down, my application loads further datasets. It is also a common approach to use a button "Load futher items" instead scoll-events.

Comment: Table wouldn't be appropriate both presentation wise and semantically.  Both of those other approaches seem marginally better, however I think my thinking is in the wrong direction.

Comment: I've added an image to the OP, would you recommend Twitter/Facebook like ajax loading? (scroll to the bottom, ajax loads more records) Edit: ah yes @SimontheSourcecoderer, just noticed your answer.  I've been meaning to learn how to do it for a while, can't seem to find any tutorials to give me a hand in the right direction though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of frontend performance of appending elements, it's faster to build an array of jQuery objects and then bulk append. jQuery can handle the array, it does something behind the scenes that makes it much faster than individual `.append()` calls:

Use an array

```
var works = [];
```

And iterate through your data, on each iteration adding to the array. For example:

```
works.push( $('<li></li>')
          .addClass('wo')
          .append($('<h2></h2>')
              .text(item.WorksOrderNumber + '/A-' + item.OperationNumber)
          )
        ) );
```

This is perhaps even faster than that, though it needs investigating. The result would be the same:

```
works.push( $('<li class="wo"><h2>' + item.WorksOrderNumber + '/A-' + item.OperationNumber + '</h2></li>');
```

Once your array is ready to go, then `.append(works)` on your container.

Here's a jsperf test proving this is faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-one-by-one-vs-bulk.

An even faster way is to use fragments as shown in the fragment example in that jsperf test, you may want to read into fragments before taking that approach.

Also, you mention about the loop being called up to 5000 times. Assuming these are up to 5000 records that you're referring to, if at all possible you may want to investigate some kind of pagination or filtering on the server side. Let your server side code do the heavy lifting!

Comment: Amazing results in the tests there!  I would like to avoid doing partial loading/pagination where possible, as each of the records in those lists are sortable by user, all becomes a nightmare.
So I think I will attempt to implement what you have given, if there are noticeable improvement I hopefully won't have to go down the pagination path.  Thanks very much Josh.

Comment: Perfect, implemented it and there are noticeable speed improvements, it's also much more maintainable now (used backslash in JS to denote line breaks) in your second 'perhaps faster' code example so it looks just like HTML, thanks again!